# Viewing CALayers in Debug View Hierarchy

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-animation

I was trying to work on a layer-hosting View in Objective-C as per the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsview/1483695-wantslayer?language=objc)

```
view.layer = [CALayer new];  // Create a layer-hosting view as opposed to a layer-backed view
view.wantsLayer = YES;
```

I go on to use this layer-hosting view to support a hierarchy of layers by appending further layers using [`addSubLayer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410833-addsublayer?language=objc).

Now my query is whether it's possible to view these children/hosted `CALayer`s in the [Debug View Hierarchy](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/ExaminingtheViewHierarchy.html)? I only see the `NSView`s but not the hosted layers. I was seeking something akin to what's available in Visual Studio as the [Live Visual Tree](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xaml-tools/inspect-xaml-properties-while-debugging?view=vs-2019#inspect-xaml-properties) where it shows both the platform views and the Visual layers.

XCode Version: 11.3

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes you can, when in the Debug View Hierarchy, click on Editor -> Show Layers, like so:

[image]

This feature was made possible from Xcode 11.4 onwards: https://twitter.com/hrrsn/status/1225168226507612161

So unfortunately you will need to upgrade your Xcode 11.3.